# ROS Kinetic Husky Question

Tags: husky, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

When looking at the installation for the Clearpath HUSKY, the current available ISO image is for ROS Indigo.  Is there an ISO Image for ROS kinetic?

Thanks,
John

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253648/ros-kinetic-husky-question/) by [jfdebard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29240/jfdebard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-02-02

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi John,

We are currently working on kinetic release for the Husky, there is no ISO currently but rather a general [Kinetic](http://packages.clearpathrobotics.com/stable/images/latest/xenial-kinetic/amd64/) iso.  In addition, there is a [kinetic-devel](https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/kinetic-devel) that works minus the microstrain imu option. For kinetic, we made the  husky a changes to the husky metapackakge layout so please blacklist desktop packages to avoid installing the desktop environment. We do hope to have a full release soon.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2017-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2017-02-08**:
Will the jackal have a kinetic release as well?

**Comment by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) on 2017-02-15**:
It will eventually.

**Comment by [pavolusa](https://answers.ros.org/users/30214/pavolusa/) on 2017-04-30**:
Hi guys,

I have the same problem with using Husky in ROS Kinetic.
Is there any progress? when will be a kinetic release?
Thank you!
Pavolusa

**Comment by [AndreasG](https://answers.ros.org/users/31096/andreasg/) on 2017-07-18**:
Any news on Husky for Kinetic?

**Comment by [TomJacobs](https://answers.ros.org/users/22616/tomjacobs/) on 2017-07-25**:
Would love to see a husky on kinetic!

**Comment by [Abdu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30451/abdu/) on 2017-10-30**:
I will start using husky, I have ros kinetic and indigo too, it seems that it has not released yet for kinetic?? is there is version for kinetic ?

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2017-11-23**:
There is a Kinetic branch: https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/kinetic-devel and you can read this link for troubleshooting: https://github.com/husky/husky/issues/66. It seems that the two main developers working on this left Clearpath Robotics.....